# Unable to unlock bootloader for HTC 816G android phone

Tags: root-access, bootloader, htc

I unable to unlock the bootloader for HTC 816G. I am trying to do this on a windows 10 laptop. The issue is that when I enter command 'adb devices', there is no device found when the phone is on fastboot mode. However, the same command works when the phone is on normal boot mode. I have installed HTC Sync and there seems to be no issue with driver. However, I tried to manually update the driver to "Android adb device" but issue persisted. I can see the phone serial number when I run 'fastboot devices' when phone is on fastboot mode. I tried to do this on an Ubuntu machine and still the same. Please assist.

Do let me know if you require any more details.

Comment: Adb doesn't work in fastboot mode. They are independent protocols. Adb works when OS is running (normal or recovery). Fastboot works at bootloader stage when no OS is loaded.

Comment: Oh..thanks for the information, @IrfanLatif. Would you know why the command 'fastboot oem get_identifier_token' fails when I run it?

Comment: `fastboot oem` commands are not standard but device-specific and I don't have any experience with HTC devices. You can check with XDA for some guides related to your device.

Comment: In addition, I'd recommend that you check the Windows device manager and see if the Fastboot device has its drivers installed. Also, consider using one of the newest versions of fastboot.exe.

Comment: Do you have the phone in fastboot mode? https://www.hardreset.info/devices/htc/htc-desire-825/fastboot-mode/

Comment: "I can see the phone serial number when I run 'fastboot devices' when phone is on fastboot mode." It seems fastboot works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I only have experience with an old HTC Wildfire S so please be patient with me here...

• The first step towards unlocking **Any HTC**  bootloader is to make an official account with HTC Dev.    [HTCDev.com](https://www.htcdev.com/register/)

( Become a HTC Developer -  so to speak )

• Secondly you need to Unlock the bootloader using the official HTC Bootloader unlock tools... 
 [HTC Dev.com/bootloader](https://www.htcdev.com/bootloader)

The process usually goes as follows...

- Enter Fastboot
- Enter Command `fastboot oem get-unlock-token`

You place the unlock token into the website and then it will convert the Token into a Token.bin or something like that ( unlock.bin ) i can't remember, i said bare with me...

- You place the (.bin) file next to your fastboot.exe program ( not ADB ) and then run
- `fastboot oem unlock -pathToUnlock.bin`

You will get appropriate instructions on the HTC Dev site so don't worry about my crappy guide ;) ...

--

---

P.S
ADB is only uses while the device is "Live" .. Fastboot is used to flash things like the System...

ADB is a part of the system, Fastboot is part of the Boot... Different programs for different things.